# Flutter Unit Test, Two equal instances are failing

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I'm expecting two instances to be equal.

I wrote the code below:

```
  test('Should return a valid model when the user is fetched from the api',
      () async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap =
        json.decode(fixture('login_fixture.json'));
    final result = LoginModel.fromJson(jsonMap);
    expect(result, testingLoginModel);
  });
```

It's failed with the following messages:

```
  Expected: <Instance of 'LoginModel'>
    Actual: <Instance of 'LoginModel'>
  00:01 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

as we can see the expected result is equal the actual one "<Instance of 'LoginModel'>"

So why it is failing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two different instances of LoginModel. Even if they have same values, they are not equal.

Update your model with

```
class LoginModel{
 String name = "some";

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is LoginModel && other.name == name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

or use

https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Answer (score 0):

You can use by below method

```
  expect(loginViewmodel.loginResponseData.value, isA<BaseApiResponse<LoginResponse>>());
```

Here my loginResponseData is my response which is coming from the API response
and isA<> is used for type matching so you can pass your response model

For more information please follow the below link
[Test Cases for API in Flutter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-write-testcases-for-api-calls-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the same instances of expected & actual but like It was said before, they can be not equal.
My model was long & full of values and == with hashCode didn't work for me.

I was using https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail for unit test which done its purpose well and
https://pub.dev/packages/equatable  made it for me.

If You're going to use it in your model, use it like this (All member variables must be final ! )
:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

        class YourModel extends Equatable {
          const YourModel({required this.value1,
            required this.value2,
        
        ....
         });
        
          final String value1;
          final String value2;
    ....
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [
            value1,
            value2,
    ... ]; ....}
```

If You also using json add this:

```
    factory YourModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return YourModel(
     value1: json['example...']['...']['...']['...']['...'],
    value2....                      );
      }
    }
```